# Return type of Region of Interest?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, roi

I am a beginner in OpenCV and am facing this difficulty.

Recently, I wrote a code in which the function makes a region of interest of a specified image.

```
def detectCellVal(img,x):
    for k in range(0, 6):
            for j in range (0, 6):
                    imroi=img[k*100:(k+1)*100, j*100:(j+1)*100]
```

Now, the program works fine when it is run through IDLE. But when I run it through cmd by entering the path, I get an error:

NoneType object has no attribute '*getitem*'

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that's exactly the code you've got there? Because that looks like invalid syntax to me...

Comment: Ah yes. I've edited it. It's imroi=img[k*100:(k+1)*100, j*100:(j+1)*100]

Comment: If the error is at that line, you probably forgot to initialize `img`. There seems to be no problem with the line itself, you should post a minimal example reproducing the error.